# ExternalProject_Add initial svn co not executed

Tags: svn, cmake, svn-checkout

**UPDATE minimal working example**

I have created a minimal working example in a public svn [repo](https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/eternapprojectmwe/trunk/proj). `Checkout` the `proj` folder from trunk, it has a CMakeLists.txt and main.cpp (code below posted). In the trunk I also have the `lib` folder, which is the static library implementing a class. This class is used in my main. I'm behind a proxy, so I have in the `~/.subversion/server` added the global proxy setup.

**Expected behavior**: After checkout of **proj** do `cmake .` which also does a checkout  **lib** and executes a `make` to create `libmylib.a` prior to build my `main`. Finally `make` my main project.

**Actual behavior**: Does not checkout **lib** so `libmylib.a` is not built. Error message:

```
Re-run cmake no build system arguments
-- Found Subversion: /usr/bin/svn (found version "1.8.8") 
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:48 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:
 /home/user/tmp/externalProject_Test/trunk/proj/project_mylib/lib/mylib.hpp
  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/tmp/externalProject_Test/trunk/proj
```

The folders are generated by `ExternalProject_add`, but no svn co in `trunk/proj/project_mylib/lib`

MWE main.cpp:

```
#include "project_mylib/lib/mylib.hpp"
int main () {
  Talker me; 
  me.say(); 
  return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

### Try to add external project 
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(project_mylib
    PREFIX project_mylib 
    SVN_REPOSITORY "https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/eternapprojectmwe/trunk/lib/"
#   SVN_REVISION ""         
#   SVN_USERNAME "" 
#   SVN_PASSWORD ""
    SVN_TRUST_CERT 1  
    TIMEOUT 30
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    SOURCE_DIR "project_mylib/lib"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BINARY_DIR "project_mylib/lib"
    BUILD_COMMAND  make
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(project_mylib binary_dir) 
project(main)
SET(LIB_DIR ${binary_dir})
SET(SOURCES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)
SET(HEADERS ${LIB_DIR}/mylib.hpp)
add_custom_command(TARGET project_mylib
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND echo ${LIB_DIR}
)
include_directories(
    include
    ${LIB_DIR}  
)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS} ${LIB_DIR}) 
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} project_mylib) 
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIB_DIR}/libmylib.a)
```

mylib.cpp:

```
#include "mylib.hpp"
 Talker::Talker()
{
    this->text = "Hello!";
}
 bool Talker::say(void)
{
    cout << this->text;
    return true;    
}
```

mylib.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Talker {
   string text;
  public:
    Talker();
    bool say(void);
};
```

Makefile for the static library

```
# Specify extensions of files to delete when cleaning
CLEANEXTS   = o a 

# Specify the target file and the install directory
OUTPUTFILE  = libmylib.a
INSTALLDIR  = .

# Default target
.PHONY: all
all: $(OUTPUTFILE)

# Build libjohnpaul.a from john.o, paul.o, and johnpaul.o
$(OUTPUTFILE): mylib.o
    ar ru $@ $^
    ranlib $@

# No rule to build john.o, paul.o, and johnpaul.o from .cpp 
# files is required; this is handled by make's database of
# implicit rules

.PHONY: install
install:
    mkdir -p $(INSTALLDIR)
    cp -p $(OUTPUTFILE) $(INSTALLDIR)

.PHONY: clean 
clean:
    for file in $(CLEANEXTS); do rm -f *.$$file; done

# Indicate dependencies of .ccp files on .hpp files
mylib.o: mylib.hpp
```

**Original post**

I have a `ROS` package (**pomdp_planner**) linked with a `Makefiel` project (**project_appl**). I have both projects on our `SVN` but different locations (I'm behind a proxy). If I have a fresh checkout of the ROS node and build it, it fails to download the `Makefile` project, so building fails at linking phase. In case I manually checkout the Makefile project at the desired location then the ROS PKG is built

My issue is that the `Makefile` project in the `externalproject_add()` is not updated to the current version on SVN and it isn't even checked out at the beginning. To build the ROS pkg I use `catkin_tools`.

I working on `Ubuntu` 14.04, `cmake` 2.8.12.2 (and ROS Indigo).

My ROS pkg CMakeList:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

### Try to add external project 
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(project_appl
    PREFIX project_appl 
    SVN_REPOSITORY "mySVN.server"
    SVN_REVISION ""         
    SVN_USERNAME "user" 
    SVN_PASSWORD "pwd"
    SVN_TRUST_CERT 1  
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    SOURCE_DIR "project_appl/src"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BINARY_DIR "project_appl/src"
    BUILD_COMMAND  make
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(project_appl binary_dir)

project(pomdp_planner)    
SET(APPL_LIB_DIR ${binary_dir})
add_custom_command(TARGET project_appl
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND cmake -E remove_directory ${binary_dir}/Utils/boost
    COMMAND cp ${binary_dir}/libappl.a ./CMakeFiles/pomdp_planner.dir/src/libappl.a
    COMMAND cp ${binary_dir}/OnlineOPSolver/OnlineOPsolver/solverOP_lib.hpp ../../devel/include/pomdp_planner/solverOP_lib.hpp
    )    
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS 
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)    
 add_service_files(
   FILES
   PlannerAction.srv 
 )    
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
 )    
SET(SOURCES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp)
SET(HEADERS ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/OnlineOPSolver/OnlineOPsolver/solverOP_lib.hpp 
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/OfflineSolver/GlobalResource.h
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/OfflineSolver/solverUtils.h
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Parser/Cassandra/Parser.h
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Parser/Cassandra/POMDP.h
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Parser/ParserSelector.h 
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Models/MOMDP/MOMDP.h
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Algorithms/SARSOP/SARSOP.h 
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Algorithms/OPMDP/OPMDP.h
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Bounds/BackupAlphaPlaneMOMDP.h
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Bounds/BackupBeliefValuePairMOMDP.h 
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/OnlineOPSolver/OnlineOPsolver/dataLogger.h
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Bounds/FastInfUBInitializer.h
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Bounds/FullObsUBInitializer.h
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Utils/CPTimer.h 
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Core/BeliefCache.h
 )    
SET(APPL_DIR 
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/OnlineOPSolver/OnlineOPsolver/
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/OfflineSolver/
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Parser/Cassandra/include
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Parser/Cassandra/
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Parser/
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Parser/POMDPX/
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Models/MOMDP
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Algorithms/SARSOP
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Algorithms/OPMDP/
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Bounds/
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Utils/
    #${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Utils/boost
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Core/
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/MathLib
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Algorithms
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/Parser/POMDPX
)    
SET(LINKER_FLAG "-std=c++11 -fpermissive")    
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS ${APPL_LIB_DIR}  
  LIBRARIES pomdp_planner  project_appl
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_generation
  DEPENDS system_lib 
)    
add_definitions(${LINKER_FLAG})
${APPL_DIR}/libappl.a)    
include_directories(
    include
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${APPL_LIB_DIR}
    ${APPL_DIR} 
)     
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS} ${APPL_LIB_DIR})     
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} project_appl) 
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${ROS_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${APPL_LIB_DIR}/libappl.a)
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal example that we can run, too? And what's the output of your CMake run?

Comment: I hope this MWE helps to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration looks fine, a little bug seems to appear in your CMakeLists.txt: the *project(main)* should appear before the external project include part. Hope this helps.